# Two-Column Layout - Divs Leave Extra Space

Tags: html, css

Firstly, I'd like to say that I don't want to do this with Javascript.

http://jsfiddle.net/WqrBY/2/

In this jsFiddle, I've got two columns but the bottom right div is obviously aligned with the bottom left. I'd like to be able to (without adjusting the markup) move the bottom right div just under the top right (just like how the bottom left is under the top left).

I don't want to change the markup because the order of the divs is important when it switches to a one-column layout for smaller screen sizes.

Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: not possible without JS or markup changes

Comment: I concur that it's impossible with the given constraints.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to preface this with saying I'm not sure why this works... I'm going to keep fiddling to test it. Comments welcome.

Here's my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tracyfu/WqrBY/3/)

Edit:

I know that you specifically mentioned that you don't want to 'change' the markup because of the `div` ordering. Would you be open to adding to the markup? This shouldn't change the order of information, but it might be a simple fix to what you're trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/tracyfu/WqrBY/7/

Comment: Clever solution. Don't forget the IE7 inline-block workaround - add `zoom: 1; *display: inline;` to your inline-block elements to cause it to work properly in IE7.  It works because the left two elements are floating left, regardless of what the right two elements do.

Comment: I think that the idea here is that either the left or the right could be the taller side, and that there should be no large gap between `#top-left`/`#bottom-left` *or* `#top-right`/`#bottom-right`. Layouts like this are what [jQuery Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) was created for, because it's just not possible with CSS (that's supported in all commonly used browsers).

Comment: @thirtydot Agree. Masonry and other tiled sites require JS for layout. I think I misunderstood waffles's requirement that all the containers be dynamic. Will edit my response :)

Comment: Compare how your modified version behaves when changing the browser width to how the original version behaves. I don't think the new resize behaviour is going to be acceptable :(

Comment: @thirtydot Sorry, I neglected to add a presumptive clearfix I also upped 60%/30% to 60%/40% up from the original widths so they actually equal 100% and I handle the margins in the `divs` themselves. I updated my fiddle to v7. Does that work?

Comment: I suspect it's not what the OP is looking for because setting percent based `margin` and `padding` won't work pleasantly. It might be close enough though; I can't speak for the OP.